# /bin/sh: get: command not found

Tags: curl, get, cron, fetch

When I try to run a script by cron I get this error messaege:

> /bin/sh: get: command not found

I also tried it in bash shell, and I tried 'curl', 'wget' and 'fetch' but non of them helped.

Can anybody tell solution? : D

Comment: Sounds like you need to install `get`, or make sure it's in cron's $PATH. What is the output of `which get` on the command line? More info would help, including the source of the script you're running, and the line in your crontab.

Comment: I only can use the crontab through the Iworx control panel : /
So I can't install anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also try this:

```
lynx -dump "http://www.example.com" > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. : )

Answer (score 0):

What OS, and what is the script that you're trying to run?

If it's trying to fetch a file from a url, try substituting get with wget. That might work.

Comment: The script just sends a mail, and I forgot it from my question that I tried wget too.

Answer (score 0):

Linux

`/usr/local/bin.something.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Some script ehere
```

Crontab:

```
00 *    * * *   root    /usr/local/bin/something.sh
```

All elements should be listed above :-)

Answer (score 0):

cron(8) uses sh(1) to execute commands.  The environment that sh(1) sees might not be the environment that you see interactively.  If so, then you can enhance the profile files to obtain the same environment or have cron(8) execute a command that obtains the correct environment (e.g. `bash -l -c '...'`).